# How to run a PoS private network with geth & lighthouse?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, proof-of-stake, genesis, lighthouse

So far for testing contracts, transactions and other dApp experiments

I had worked with pre-established testnets (Rinkeby, Goerli etc)

now i am tasked with deploying a private PoS network based on geth + lighthouse

how can i do this ?

my understanding is that we need 32 eth deposited in a deposit contract BUT when we start a PoS chain as a private network - we don't have any contract neither any deposit

So how can we deploy a PoS private blockchain, on geth + lighthouse, such that we have a pre-deployed deposit contract and validators who already have deposited balances on this contract, right from the start - i.e Genesis ?